# Append and unique : Python

Tags: append, unique

I am new to python and I want to append two lists in the following way:

```
list1=[2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2008, 2013, 2014]

list2=['Bahamas, The', 'Bahamas, The', 'Bahamas, The', 'Bahamas, The', 'Bahamas, The', 'Bahamas, The', 'Bahamas, The', 'Bahamas, The', 'Bahamas, The', 'Bahrain', 'Guyana', 'Guyana']
```

length of list 1 and list 2 are always equal in any condition.

```
I want the output to be :
2006: [’Bahamas, The’] 
2007: [’Bahamas, The’] 
2008: [’Bahamas, The’, ’Bahrain’] 
2009: [’Bahamas, The’] 
2010: [’Bahamas, The’] 
2011: [’Bahamas, The’] 
2012: [’Bahamas, The’] 
2013: [’Bahamas, The’, ’Guyana’] 
2014: [’Bahamas, The’, ’Guyana’]
```

Comment: Based on what condition 2008, 2013 & 2014 have additional value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the data structure you're looking for is a dictionary.

Using this data structure, we can do the following.

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

Create a new defaultdict and pass it `list`.

```
d = defaultdict(list)
```

Next we need to `zip` the two lists.
This can be done with:

```
zip(list1, list2)
```

If you're using Python 2, this will return a list (great, easy).
However, if you're using Python 3, this produces a generator (see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)). So, if you're using Python 3 (like me) to see what this thing looks like you can convert the generator to a list as follows:

```
list(zip(list1, list2))
```

Which is something like this:

```
[(2006, 'Bahamas, The'), (2007, 'Bahamas, The'), (2008, 'Bahamas, The')...]
```

Now all we have to do is iterate through this object as follows:

```
for k, v in zip(list1, list2):
    d[k].append(v)
```

So, all together:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(list1, list2):
    d[k].append(v)
```

To see the result you can use:

```
for k, v in d.items(): # iteritems if Python 2
    print(k, v)
```

This yields:

```
2006 ['Bahamas, The']
2007 ['Bahamas, The']
2008 ['Bahamas, The', 'Bahrain']
2009 ['Bahamas, The']
2010 ['Bahamas, The']
2011 ['Bahamas, The']
2012 ['Bahamas, The']
2013 ['Bahamas, The', 'Guyana']
2014 ['Bahamas, The', 'Guyana']
```

---

FYI.

If you'd really like a list, and not a dictionary, you can use:

```
list(d.items())     # Python 3

list(d.iteritems()) # Python 2
```